# Return all data if variable is NULL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a query that returns data based on a user input variable (@VariantID).

```
WHERE sod.ProductVariantID = @VariantID
```

The problem is that if @VariableID is NULL, I want to return all data regardless of what sod.ProductVariantID equals.

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Any particular flavor of sql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `OR` condition , checking for `NULL` value or equal condition `=`.

```
WHERE @VariantID is NULL OR sod.ProductVariantID = @VariantID
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's SQL Server you can use ISNULL as an alternative to @RADAR answer.

```
WHERE sod.ProductVariantID = ISNULL(@VariantID,sod.ProductVariantID)
```

Depending on the context of your query prefer use a control statement such as:

```
IF @VariantID IS NULL 
   SELECT ...
ELSE
   SELECT ... WHERE sod.ProductVariantID = @VariantID
```